# FireBug: Duplicates in NET panel - one unending, the other does not show response body

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox4

Using FireFox 4 + FireBug 1.7 on Win7.

In my Net panel, I see 2 entries for each URL (both for the main HTML
and included scripts).

For each of these:
First entry looks unfinished (yellow line, loader rolling, 0 in all
time fields, size is "?").
Second entry looks successful (200 OK, correct size, correct response
headers, etc.), but does not show any response body :-(

As a result (at least I think that's the causality here), I can't
debug any of my scripts, because the script panel shows up blank for
all my scripts.

This happens also for any site (e.g. google.com), not just my stuff.
Rebooted, Reinstalled FF + FB, but still no luck.

Help ...
Anyone ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem all morning!  Was pulling out my hair for quite a while.  It turned out to be the proxy server for my company.  I previously had Firefox set to autodetect proxy settings.  Simply changing the setting to automatic, manual, or none solved my issues.

Note that duplicate entries were showing up in the NET panel as you describe as well as I was receiving duplicated entries in the console panel.

Comment: Thanks ! "Use system proxy settings" is also flaky for me, but Manual seems to work perfect.